Why does continuous wavelet transform vary depending on if you analyze the full signal or just a part of it?
Suppose you have a signal such as this:

Note this is a made up signal from paleoclimate data to illustrate my question. It is the same million-year long signal back-to-back, with the second half multiplied by 0.75.
If I perform a continuous wavelet transform (CWT; note I realize this is actually calculated discretely since it is on a computer) analysis over the whole signal, I get the following:

However, if I perform the CWT over the first half of the signal, I get this:

whereas the CWT over the second half of the signal yields:

My question is, why isn't the CWT of the whole signal simply the combination of the CWT of the first and second half? My understanding the that the CWT gives information about amplitude and frequency as a signal varies through time; at a given point in time in the original signal, why should the convolution of the signal with the wavelet depend on non-local aspects of the signal?
Thank you!
